# Remote Repository Connection

Tags: svn, remote-access, subclipse, remote-server, subversive

I am building an SVN repository on a public IP server at work so that some Devs including myself can access it from anywhere not just from the office. I was wondering how do I get the URL for the SVN Repository i know a local one is file:///svn_repos but I've never tried to do anything like this before. Sorry if I seem like a complete idiot.

Comment: Are your network admins & data security people involved in this? Exposing your repository to the public internet can be very risky & there are a number of precautions you must take. Why not host it internally (still on Apache, because you can't host a shared repository with *file:///* anyway) and VPN into the company network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download and install Subversion Edge on the server:

http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion

This will give you a simple web UI for managing your server and repositories.  Your clients will be able to access your repositories via http or https.

Answer (score 2):

You have to connect your svn server with apache running on the same box.

This might help you http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, follow these steps : https://www.inetsolution.com/blog/july-2007/how-to-setup-subversion-apache-websvn-on-windo (never tested but it seems right)

For Linux, you need apache, subversion and mod_dav_svn (install it with apt-get, yum or whatsoever)

1. Install apache
2. Install subversion
3. Install mod_dav_svn

Then you have to configure everything.
In apache configuration, you add this :

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /var/www/svnrepo
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion repositories"
  AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-users
  Require valid-user
  SSLRequireSSL
</Location>
```

You create your certificate :

```
openssl req -new > YOUR_SERVER.certificate.csr
openssl rsa -in privkey.pem -out YOUR_SERVER.certificate.key
openssl x509 -in YOUR_SERVER.certificate.csr -out YOUR_SERVER.certificate.cert -req -      signkey YOUR_SERVER.certificate.key -days 1024
mv YOUR_SERVER.certificate.cert /etc/pki/tls/certs/
mv YOUR_SERVER.certificate.key /etc/pki/tls/private/
vim /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf
```

You create your users :

```
htpasswd -cm /etc/svn-auth-users YOUR_USERNAME
```

You create and configure your svn server :

```
cd /var/www
mkdir svn
cd svn
svnadmin create YOUR_PROJECT_NAME
chown -R apache.apache YOUR_PROJECT_NAME
chcon -h system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/svnrepo/YOUR_PROJECT_NAME
chcon -R -h apache:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/svnrepo/YOUR_PROJECT_NAME/*

mkdir -p /var/svn_template/{trunk,branches,tags}
svn import -m 'Initial import' /var/svn_template/ https://localhost/svn/YOUR_PROJECT_NAME/
service httpd restart
```

I have done this on several Fedora servers and it works very well.

Then, you can access your svn server at this address : 
**https://YOUR_SERVER_ADDRESS/svn/YOUR_PROJECT_NAME/** with your **YOUR_USERNAME** account (and its **password** )

Comment: I've edited it. ;) https://www.inetsolution.com/blog/july-2007/how-to-setup-subversion-apache-websvn-on-windo